# Migrate from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 with version control

Tags: sharepoint-2010, migration, sharepoint-2013

Good morning everyone.

I have a local server with a SharePoint Foundation 2010 site that contains a documents library with version control and own metadata (ie, new columns containing information).

I need to migrate this SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint Online (which is 2013 version) or an Office 365 license with SharePoint 2013.

Is it possible to perform this migration while retaining the specified library with all versions of documents and values of their new metadata?

If it's not possible direct migration, would it be possible to migrate local SharePoint 2010 to 2013 and then migrate the local server to on-line keeping the library as in the previous case?

Thank you very much in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your requirement can be met by a tool called ShareGate. You can use trial version to finish the migration.

Check below the link to ShareGate web site
http://en.share-gate.com/

Comment: Thanks Hiren. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Not only Sharegate, there are lot of Third party tools were available for Migrating SharePoint from 2010 to 2013. Also, most of these tools will offer an evaluation version for few days that you can analyze and conclude with what tool will match your requirement. Try every tool and move forward with the one you choose.